# What is the best gelling agent for gummies?

Tags: candy, gelling-agents

So, today I did my first attempt at home made gummies using 35g of gelatine with 1 cup water and 1/2 cup sugar.  When it cooled though, all I had was really tough jello.  Should I just add more gelatine, or is there another chemical I could use?  I have looked at methylcellulose, carrageenan, agar, cornstarch, and pectin in addition to gelatine, but there doesn't seem to be a good comparison of these on the web.  Additionally, if anyone has insight into special techniques I could use, it would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I believe the key element that you are missing would be *corn syrup*. The recipe I work with (in a link below) uses

- 1 box Jell-o gelatin
- 2 packages unflavored gelatin
- 1/4 cup corn syrup
- 1/2 cup of COLD water *(the cold water is important to the consistency as
  well)*

If you want to skip the packaged "Jell-o", in favor of more gelatin, your own flavoring and sugar, do use extra fine sugar (caster) as this will also improve the texture of your finished product.

When I first started trying to make gummies I found ["The King of Random" with this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3_dV-e4d9c). 
I've made several batches since then and found them to be very good. (Even got the [lego molds from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EJXT5Y0), although he also shows you [how to make the lego molds too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRwLxSwXpuM)...). Do watch the video as it contains several good tips beyond just the recipe. 
           [image]

Some of the tips include:

- allow the syrup to rest to remove some impurities.
- add ground up vitamin c to add a sour edge to your candies (and make them 'healthier')
- use a condiment bottle (squeezable) to pour the syrup into your molds
- allow the syrup to completely gel once and remelt (after cutting away the foam) for and even cleaner/clearer result

(note: as an added bonus this was how I discovered "[The King of Random](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1zZE_kJ8rQHgLTVfobLi_g)" and his collection of remarkable videos...only some of which are 'food related')